# Using Jquery to detect zoom in/put

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a rectangle with a gray border.

When I click Command + (zoom in is more than 100%), this rectangle should have a blue border.

When I click Command - (zoom out is less than 100%), this rectangle should have a red border.

And when the browser is normal (100%), this rectangle should have a green border.

But somehow it doesn't work as expected.

Please give me a hand.  Thanks!

```js
 $(window).resize(function() {
       if(screen.width == window.innerWidth){
          /* normal page with 100% zoom */
          $('.square').attr('class', 'square').addClass('green')
       } else if(screen.width > window.innerWidth){
           /*zoomed in the page more than 100% */
           $('.square').attr('class', 'square').addClass('blue')
       } else {
           /* zoomed out less than 100%*/
           $('.square').attr('class', 'square').addClass('red')
       }
    });
```

```css
.square {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray
}
.green {
  border: 2px solid green
 }
.red {
  border: 2px solid red
}
.blue {
  border: 2px solid blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
 if ( $(window).width() > 800 ){
   $('.square').attr('class', 'square').addClass('red')
 }
 else if ( $(window).width() < 800 )
 {
    if($(window).width() == 798)
    {
      $('.square').attr('class', 'square').addClass('green')
    }
    else
    {
      $('.square').attr('class', 'square').addClass('blue')
    }
 }
 else 
 {
   $('.square').attr('class', 'square').addClass('green')
 }
});
```

```css
.square {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray
}
.green {
  border: 2px solid green
 }
.red {
  border: 2px solid red
}
.blue {
  border: 2px solid blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square">
</div>
```

Please Try this code. i hope this code help to you.

Comment: Thanks, @Mitali Patel for sharing your code!